# How to add object / value to a certain element on NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I only know method addObject, which is add object to the next element in the array. I want to be able to add / set / update object to an arbitrary position at the NSMutableArray, ex:

```
arr[105] = @(true);
arr[709] = @(30);
arr[1010] = @"Hello world!";
NSLog (@"%@", arr[1010]);
```

I have been trying something like this, but the next time I tried to retrieve the value, it says nil. How to do this? Thanks.

EDIT: last time I tried, it gave me error: `index 1010 beyond bounds for empty array.`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you specify a size when you create an array, the specified size is regarded as a “hint”; the actual size of the array is still 0. This means that you cannot insert an object at an index greater than the current count of an array. For example, if an array contains two objects, its size is 2, so you can add objects at indices 0, 1, or 2. Index 3 is illegal and out of bounds.

read more at https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/index.html

below method use for replace existing object at index with new object

```
[self.arr replaceObjectAtIndex:<#(NSUInteger)#> withObject:<#(nonnull id)#>]
```

below method use for insert new object at index

```
[self.arr insertObject:<#(nonnull id)#> atIndex:<#(NSUInteger)#>]
```

Ex:

if object already available at index and replace with new object

```
[self.arrayBuyers replaceObjectAtIndex:1010 withObject:@"Hello world!"]
```

add new object at index

```
[self.arr insertObject:1 atIndex:@"Hi"];
```

Comment: Thanks! Let me try it. Meanwhile, I have updated the question, which might gives you additional info in understanding the issue.

Comment: yes that error give u because there is no index available of array available for add/replace object

Comment: Thanks! So to solve this, I insert that many objects I needed before using the array. I'm not sure if this is the right way, but at least I can move on. I'll optimise this later.